# Problem in Installing Gnome 3.12

Tags: gnome, upgrade, package-management, ppa

I tried to install Gnome 3.12 on my Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 (Gnome shell: 3.10)
I did the following steps (from [this](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-gnome-3-12-on-ubuntu-gnome-14-04-trusty-tahr/) tutorial):

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The problem is that when I enter `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, it says there are no new packages to be installed:

```
hamed@hamed-N56JRH:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  kde-l10n-engb kde-l10n-fa
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Seems like `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` doesn't add list of new packages...

Comment: Sounds like you didn't run apt-get update

Comment: I confirm this issue, after adding these repositories the `gnome-desktop3` package remains unavailable. You might wish to file a bug at [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/~gnome3-team).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...
Neither the code nor the packages have problem...
The problem is between Iran(the country i live in) and Google.
The repositories from Google wouldn't allow the 'apt-get update' run successfully (due to the SANCTIONS!:D), so i unchecked the repositories from Google in my software center and everything went right after that...